# .Net Windows Service hanging on startup

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm unable to get a .Net Windows service to run on my machine. When I start the service, it seems to hang and I get the message saying that it took an unusual amount of time to respond. I see 3 instances of the service in the task manager but I am unable to kill them. From that point I am also unable to install/uninstall any windows services until I reboot. It seems to prevent the machine shutting down too as I need to use the power button when I want to reboot.

My machine is Windows 10 and the service is .Net 4.5.2. The service is empty ie. OnStart and OnStop have no code (constructor has InitializeComponent()). I've been writing/using services for years but have never seen anything like this. There is nothing in the event viewer so I have no idea how to debug it.

Has anybody seen this or knows how to fix/debug it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Windows Event Viewer and seeing if any errors generated from your service in there?

Comment: To debug services the easyest way i've found is dropping a `Debugger.Break();` in sensitive parts. That way the service drops back to the Visual Studio and you can debug it from there

Comment: You can also attach the Visual Studio debugger to your service once it has hung: Debug, Attach to Process.

Comment: I did try attaching the debugger once it had hung but the service was greyed out in Visual Studio, so it wouldn't let me.

Comment: I tried Debugger.Break() in the first line of Program.Main but it doesn't get hit.

Comment: From Windows 8 and on i think you must change a registry key for `Debugger.Break()` to work. See [this](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/61829)